# Pass dataset between forms, using DataSet Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset

I'm wanting to pass a DataSet from one form to another.  This works fine, but it breaks the BindingSources.  I either have to redo all the BindingSource.DataSource (e.g. bindingSourceItems.DataSource = myDataSet.Items).
If I set the DataSet before InitializeComponent() within the form is called and then edit the Designer.cs file to check if the forms DataSet is not NULL; and thereform not to create a new instance of it (which clears the entire dataset), works.  It works great!  Except that now my [Deisgn] form breaks, and I cannot access it.  Becuase it's freaking out about my if Statement in the .Designer.cs file.
Anyone know how to simply just pass the DataSet from form to form without breaking the BindingSources within the form?

Comment: Assigning the new instance to the BindingSource is the intended way. Your questions sound like you have many bindingsources on your form that sound like a problem. Why do you need more then one?

Comment: I use many BindingSources in my form, for multiple datagridviews, and also for relational look-ups (combo boxes within the datagridviews).